# enable MTP in a fastboot mode

Tags: android, adb, fastboot

I want to unlock bootloader on realme 7. I enabled developer options, disabled OEM lock and turned on usb debuging. But there is a problem. ADB detects my phone only when I enable MTP (file transfering). It doesn't matter when i'm using adb in a system, but it's a problem in a fastboot mode. I can't enable MTP on this mode, so adb does no detect my phone. What should I do? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in fastboot mode, you can not use ADB.
The fastboot bootloader uses its own protocol called... fastboot.

You should have a `fasboot` binary in your SDK to communicate with your phone.
If you are on Windows, look for `fastboot.exe`.

If you are on Mac or Linux, it will likely be just `fastboot` which you many need to run with `sudo` depending on your setup.

Look here for supported commands: http://adbcommand.com/fastboot

Like `adb` there is a `fastboot devices` command that should show your phone if it is properly connected.
But that is where similarities with ADB end.

If you are on Windows, you may need to install special drivers.
Consult the manufacturers site for details.